# Неверное название вкладки «Настройки» в основном профиле пользователя

Tags: предложение, локализация, страница-учётной-записи

В профиле на Мете — более верная, на мой взгляд версия:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В основном профиле:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Править и всем владеть? Думаю, что там тоже должно быть «Настройки».

Comment: «Настройки» в любом случае звучит лучше: существительное, а не глагол. Есть ли встречные предложения?

Comment: @VladD: встречные это как? Что-нибудь еще кроме «настроек»?

Comment: Ну, в смысле, может быть кто-то кто против, и у него есть _другие_ предложения? Если нет, то можно считать предложение принятым единогласно.

Comment: @VladD: думаю, что 3 голоса «за» плюс мой — это вполне единогласно. В транзифексе-то есть?

Comment: В английском оригинале в основном профиле Edit Profile & Settings, а на Мете просто Settings. Хм.

Comment: Может, «Настройки и редактирование профиля»? Тяжеловесно как-то.

Comment: @VladD: в основном есть пункт «редактировать профиль», а на Мете нет.

Comment: Угу. А как сделать так, чтобы было понятно, что профиль редактировать тоже в этом пункте меню? Если оставить только «настройки», будет вероятно не совсем очевидно.

Comment: Вряд ли это будет быстро: это могут сделать лишь разработчики движка, на уровне отдельного сайта это, боюсь, не настраивается. Так что лучше всё же думать — покамест — о «локальном» решении.